# How to add an EventListener that listens every click on window besides a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventhandler, stoppropagation

I have a simple html file that has only one input field:

```
<input value="Hello">
```

What I want is that the moment the user clicks on the input field, he/she will be able to edit the text, and then once the finish the edit and click **somewhere else** (not inside the text field) in the window, the user will get an alert with the new input.

My JS code is:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   $($('input')[0]).click(function() {
      alert('OK1');
      $(this).addClass('input-edit');
      $($(window)[0]).click(function() {
         alert('OK2');
         var text = $('input').value;
         alert(text);
      });
      $($('input')[0]).click(function(e) {
         e.stopPropagation();
         return false;
      });
   })
})
```

However, when I run the code, I see that the moment I click the first time inside the text field, the code behaves like it automatically got two clicks, so I get 3 alerts:

> OK1 OK2 undefined

Do you know what I can do to ensure that the second click behave as I expect?

Comment: For better understanding..You should also add a fiddle in your question..! It's not necessary but it's a good practice..! And alot more appealing to people to solve your issue :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the blur event. The event when an element loses focus (or cursor in this case) is called `blur` event. You just need to add an event handler to blur event of your input element. Try

```
$('input').blur(function(e) {
    alert($(this).val());
}
```

Since you have only one input element, getting the 0-indexed element is not required.

Answer (score 3):

Give and id of target or whatever like I did below and try the blur event. Moreover, here is the working JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wr1ncvbn/

```
<input type="text"/ id="target">

$('#target').blur(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```